# IDA basic block type fcb_cndret - what does it mean?

Tags: ida, disassembly, idapython, idapro-sdk

IDA Pro's `idaapi.BasicBlock` objects returned by `idaapi.FlowChart()` can be of the following types (see `gdl.hpp` in the SDK sources):

```
// flow chart block types
enum fc_block_type_t
{
  fcb_normal,    // normal block
  fcb_indjump,   // block ends with indirect jump
  fcb_ret,       // return block
  fcb_cndret,    // conditional return block
  fcb_noret,     // noreturn block
  fcb_enoret,    // external noreturn block (does not belong to the function)
  fcb_extern,    // external normal block
  fcb_error,     // block passes execution past the function end
};
```

I was able to find examples for all types except `fcb_cndret`. What does

> conditional return block

mean? Could somebody give an example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know it either so I put together this small script in order to do some *empirical* analysis.

```
import idaapi
import idc
import idautils

for f in Functions():
    fc = idaapi.FlowChart(idaapi.get_func(f))
    for bb in fc:
        if bb.type == 3:
            print "%x type: %d" % (bb.startEA, bb.type)

print "Done"
```

I throw it to several x86 and x86_64 binaries *without results*.

So, it could be that:

- This kind of block appears very rarely
- It appears only in other architectures (I didn't have any ARM or MIPS in this computer to test, sorry)
- The enum field is reserved for future use

Just my two cents.

**Update**

I tried it with an ARM binary and found a couple of them.
Apparently these are blocks in which a *conditional* instruction modifies the *PC* register (see screenshot)

[image: fcb_cndret basic blocks in ARM binary]

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Conditional returns are found in some instruction set architectures.

For example, the 8085 has instructions which will action a subroutine return if a status flag is set/clear:

```
RZ   ... return if Z flag set
RC   ... return if C flag set
RNZ  ... return if Z flag clear
...
```